# Significance of the backslash?

Tags: php

`magic_quotes_gpc`

We all hate it and many servers still use this setting and knowingly enough some provides will argue it's safer but I must disagree.

The question I have is, what would a backslash be needed for?
I want to remove them completely which I can do but I am not sure if they are needed?

*EDIT*

Other then SQL injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

magic_quotes_gpc() was provided based on the misguided notion that ALL data submitted to PHP from any external source would be immediately inserted into a database. If you wanted to send that data somewhere OTHER than a database, you had to remove the slashes that PHP just inserted, doubling the work required.

As well, not all databases use slashes for escaping metacharacters. `\'` is fine in MySQL, but in MS Access, escaping a single quote is actually `''` - so not only was PHP doing unecessary work, in many situations, it was doing the work WRONG to begin with.

And then, on top of all that, addslashes (which is basically what magic_quotes_gpc() was calling internally) can't handle all forms of SQL injection attacks, particularly where Unicode is used. addslashes is a glorified form of `str_replace("'", "\\'", $string)`, which works at the ASCII level - plenty of Unicode sequences can look like regular ascii, but get turned into SQL metacharacters after a simplistic `addslashes()` has wreaked its havoc.

Comment: I enjoyed reading your inquiry, I learned something new and it I feel this was the best answer that reassured me that it was pointless 100%.

Answer (score 1):

They are for preventing [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) exploits, a very serious issue you should read up on if you're going to be coding for the web.

You should look into prepared queries, which is a much better way of avoiding SQL injection.

Comment: I have prepared queries, that are securely handled however the slashes are added and I really do not need them added at all.

Comment: Then go ahead and disable them.

Answer (score 1):

There is no good reason to have this feature in PHP.

That's why it's officially deprecated and will not exist in future versions.

If there were good reasons to keep it, the developer community would have done so.

Answer (score 0):

They are designed to make us do extra work to remove them. For example, [some code in Dokuwiki](http://github.com/splitbrain/dokuwiki/blob/5ec3fefc5fc0983d6fdc0efdaed2e78e0d09a868/inc/init.php#L165).

Don't forget about [`magic_quotes_runtime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-runtime) too.